# Setting up a DB which can be accessed over http

Tags: mysql, tableau-api, remote-access

I am working on a POC to extract data from some devices and update in a DB. I want Tableau hosted online to connect to this DB and generate reports.

As the first step I want to setup a server ( using my PC for the testing purpose ) and allow it to host a DB ( preferably mysql) so that Tableau can connect to it.

I am very basic in terms of the IT skills.Can anyone help me in setting up this server from scratch?

Comment: Have a look at the installation guide of mysql. You could either install it locally on your machine or via a docker container. You then need a way to make your pc publicly available (e.g. via DynDNS).

Answer (score 0):

You can download a mysql client such as XAMPP, install it in your pc and run mysql database, it comes with all the tools you need to do your POC + it's free.

You can start here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmFHreVid-k